# Difference between setting layoutparams direct or in addView

Tags: android

I was wondering if there is a difference between

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams separatorParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView separator = new TextView(context);
separator.setLayoutParams(seperatorParams);

this.addView(separator);
```

Or

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams separatorParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

TextView separator = new TextView(context);

this.addView(separator,separatorParams);
```

Comment: ya lot of difference is their

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code, it basically makes no difference since `addView(View view)` calls `addView(view, view.getLayoutParams())`

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely none.

`this.addView(separator);` 
Will grab the params from the child or generate it.

Where as: `this.addView(separator,separatorParams);`
Will use the params then add it to the layout anyway.

Have a look at the source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java)